# Cambiar el nombre Untitled (Workspace) en VSC

Tags: vscode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo estas dos carpetas en un untitled (workspace). Como puedo poner otro nombre al workspace. Se que no es puramente nada de código pero tengo la duda. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente graba el workspace

[image: menu]

Comment: Ostras claro que fácil ! Gracias @Diego Torres

Comment: Estoy bloqueado de hacer más preguntas en SO y no se porque. Tengo una pregunta para tí. Como puedo tener más de 1 workspace en Visual studio ? Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿Te refieres a tener múltiples workspaces abiertos? Creo que no se puede, tienes que cerrar uno para poder abrir otro.

Comment: Lo que sí se puede es abrir múltiples ventanas de VS Code con la opción "New Window", en cada una puedes abrir un workspace diferente.

Comment: Me referia a multiples workspaces abiertos sip, gracias por la atención.